# aurelia - example, error installing dependencies

Tags: aurelia

I've been following the examples on the Aurelia site and with this one:

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/2

I run 'au new' and follow through the prompts and it gets to the "Would you like to install the project dependencies" question, and I say Yes and it then fails with the below errors. Does anyone have an idea on why? I have Node.JS and a GIT client installed.

```
Would you like to install the project dependencies?

1. Yes (Default)
   Installs all server, client and tooling dependencies needed to build
   the project.
2. No
   Completes the new project wizard without installing dependencies.

[Yes]> 1

Installing project dependencies.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-ecf98f08: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-ecf98f08: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-4b46db44: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-4b46db44: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\jnixon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: undefined

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed the GitHub desktop app (116MB). Seems this does not setup the environment variables correctly so I used the other (smaller client instead). This worked...

1. Uninstall your git client from control panel
2. Download and install this client instead https://git-scm.com/download/win
3. Try creating a new Aurelia project again

Comment: You can manually set the environment variables. There are tons of tutorials out there. I always do that because I love the github client because of the **diff** functionality, but I use the CLI in my IDE.

Comment: For others that might have the same problem that I did: I had not installed git before aurealia-cli. Uninstalling aurelia-cli using: npm uninstall aurelia-cli, then reinstalling, then creating the project again fixed things for me.