# Aurelia CLI error during "Installing project dependencies"

Tags: aurelia

What is causing this error when I try to create a new project? Is it my company's firewall?

```
Installing project dependencies.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-ecf98f08: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-ecf98f08: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-4b46db44: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-4b46db44: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\WHMCNEIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aurelia - example, error installing depencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973029/aurelia-example-error-installing-depencies)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same error. Follow the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973029/aurelia-example-error-installing-depencies?rq=1), it works for me.